# Blank page in Edge Chromium - Selenium C# EdgeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-edgedriver

**Problem**
Getting blank edge page with address as data while setting up UI automation solution with below stack.

**Stack**
Trying to create a UI Automation - with Selemium VS 2019, Edge Chromium version: 87.0.664.47
Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools:3.141.2
Selenium.WebDriver: 3.141.0 - which is compatible with Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools.

```
EdgeOptions op = new EdgeOptions();
//op.UseChromium = true;
string location = @"C:\drivers\";
EdgeDriver d = new EdgeDriver(location, op);
d.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
d.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

**Blank edge page with data:**
[image]

Comment: What is the output of the msedgedriver.exe console application?

Answer (score 0):

This line can be modified:

```
d.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Take out the `Navigate()` so it is just

```
d.Url = @"https://www.google.com";
```

Also not sure why you have commented out `d.UseChromium = true;` as that is required in order to use Chromium edge. Otherwise it will load the legacy browser.